# Thinking about PrC Arcane Hierophant

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wizard, druid, prestige-class

I'm fairly new to DnD, currently I'm playing with my second party ever. We aren't really power players, we're pretty casual players more concerned with fun than with optimizing builds. I'm a lvl 2 Druid, human, and I was thinking about prestige classing into Arcane Hierophant.

I want to accomplish this the following way:
- druid lvl 4 then;
- wizard lvl 3 then;
- AH lvl 10; 
- the rest is a long time ahead

We are (at the moment) only allowed stuff from the Core books, though I think in due time I can convince my DM to let me take on AH. Is this a good route to become an AH? I want to focus more on Druidic powers (wild shape, familiar) and have the wizard spells as second focus. Also what would be good feats

(For those of you who are wondering about my stats: str 10, dex 14, con 16, int 13, wis 16, cha 8).

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to be a Wizard if you have an Int score of 13. Your spells will be easy to resist, you will get next to no bonus spells, and you won't be able to cast any spells above level 3 unless you start increasing your Intelligence.

Comment: But given that I still have some levels to go before I even take on a wizard level, isn't there enough time in between to boost my int score via magic items?

Comment: If you don't mind the idea that a grapple check against your hat causes you to lose 50% of your prepared spells, sure. But it´s a risk you´ll be taking. And the DCs still won't be all that high.

Comment: @Leijten A wizard with a high Int score would be doing that, too, so you’ll still be (a lot) behind, plus you won’t be able to do that with your Wisdom, as a druid should.

Comment: Alas, but I already checked the path via sorcerer lvls and that didn't strike me as a good idea also. So are you suggesting to drop the idea entirely or can it be done, albeit not giving an optimal build. Again, most of my party don't seem interested in building power play characters so I don't want to go maxing out only my druid lvls so that the party is more balanced.

Comment: See http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-optimization-questions-on-topic.  If you can reform this into a question with some clearer requirements it can get reopened; unfortunately "give me general advice"  isn't on topic here, though our site chat may be a good place to go for that general advice.

Comment: Please narrow this question: focus *why* you're considering arcane hierophant, *what* you hope to get out of it, *how* you imagine this character acting.

Comment: And then what the actual question is.  Is this rules legal? Yes. Will it be fun? If you make it so. Is it optimized? No. How can I take this class progression and stats and make the character an effective... Healer? Meleer? Primary caster? <detailed answer here.> But the question should have an objectively best answer.